# Can't split .txt file into .xml files using LEX program

Tags: xml, lex

I am trying to split a big file, containing ID and text of different tweets, in separate .xml files (for each tweet, a different .xml file). My .txt file is something like this:

```
15923   #WhoIsQ #WheresTheServer #DumpNike #DECLASFISA Democrats Support Antifa, Muslim Brotherhood, MS13, ISIS, Pedophilia, Child Trafficking, Taxpayer Funded Abortion’s, Election Fraud, Sedition And Treason!!! #LockThemAllUp #WWG1WGA #QAnon ⁦@USER URL
27014   #ConstitutionDay is revered by Conservatives, hated by Progressives/Socialist/Democrats that want to change it.
30530   #FOXNews #NRA #MAGA #POTUS #TRUMP #2ndAmendment #RNC #USMC #veterans @USER    @USER @USER @USER @USER   #fakereporting #THESWAMP #dnc #liberals @USER @USER #fakeoutrage @USER  First, it reduces the ca URL
13876   #Watching #Boomer getting the news that she is still up for parole always makes me smile. #Wentworth Finale...@USER is such a treasure. URL
60133   #NoPasaran: Unity demo to oppose the far-right in #London – #antifa #Oct13 — Enough is Enough! URL
83681   . . . What the fuck did he do this time?
96874   #RAP is a form of ART! Used to express yourself freely. It does not gv the green light or excuse the behavior of acting like an animal! She is not in the streets of the BX where violence is a way of living. Elevate yourself boo and get on @USER level for longevity! #QUEEN
65507   @USER Do you get the feeling he is kissing @USER behind so he can humiliate him later?
78910   5 Tips to Enhance Audience Connection on Facebook URL @USER #socialmedia #smm URL
46363   #BiggBossTamil janani won the task. She is going to first final list
68123   #Conservatives - the party of low taxation  #Tories #Tory URL
22452   -..  The Nord cannot make a single move, but he is fully aware of what is happening. A chill comes down his spine as a ghostly, rather. . . calm female voice called for him from a corner of the room.  Before he even has time to /attempt/ a response, +
15565   #ConsTOO THE PLACE FOR FED UP CONSERVATIVES !!!
64376   #GreatAwakening #QAnon #PatriotsUnited #WWG1WGA #AreYouAwake  WHEN YOU ARE AWAKE YOU SEE CLEARLY ❤️  Check out this video URL URL
12588   @USER Nigga ware da hits at
```

As I said, the number represents the ID, and after 3 spaces it is the text of the specific tweet. What I want to do is to split this text in such way that I could obtain, for each tweet, a corresponding .xml file. For that, I use the following program, wrote in LEX:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
char s[10000], name[80], ids[10];
FILE *file;
char *p;
int id;
%}

%x spre_nume nume

%%
^[*\@.*]\n   
^\n
\[0-9]+
^\t
\[cc\]
\[cs\]

"   ". strcpy(s, yytext+3);  /* the first character in the phrase */

\n {               //itoa(id++, ids, 10);
                   strcat(name, "#");
                   sprintf(ids, "%d", id++);
                   strcat(name, ids);
                   strcat(name, ".xml");
                   file = fopen(name, "w");
           if(file != NULL) {
             fprintf(file, "%s\n", s);
printf("Open the file %s, with the pointer file %d.\n", name, file);
           } else
             fprintf(stderr,
                 "Can't open %s\n",
                 name);
                 }

. strcat(s, yytext);



^[0-9]+ {
printf("Read the name of the phrase %s\n", yytext);

        strcpy(name, yytext);
         }


%%

main()
{
  printf("The Beggining!\n");
  yylex();
}
```

After I compile it, with:

```
lex phrase.lex
gcc -o PHRASE lex.yy.c -lfl
```

and then I call the executable file into other directory, where I want to keep my .xml files, and I apply the program to the .txt file from above, the outcome is undesirable. The first tweet is correctly parsed as a .xml file, but the others aren't (some of them contain the tweets before them). For example, the second tweet, with ID 27014, looks like this:

```
    #WhoIsQ #WheresTheServer #DumpNike #DECLASFISA Democrats Support Antifa, Muslim Brotherhood, MS13, ISIS, Pedophilia, Child Trafficking, Taxpayer Funded Abortion’s, Election Fraud, Sedition And Treason!!! #LockThemAllUp #WWG1WGA #QAnon ⁦@USER URL
    #ConstitutionDay is revered by Conservatives, hated by Progressives/Socialist/Democrats that want to change it.
```

while the third tweet, with ID 30530, looks like this:

```
#fakereporting #THESWAMP #dnc #liberals @USER @USER #fakeoutrage @USER  First, it reduces the ca URL
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: That file is awfully hard to read. Could you please fix the indentation? Also, although flex mostly seems to accept rule lines with no action, they are not valid. If you want a pattern to do nothing, use `;` or `{ }` as the action. Although, as far as I can see, the patterns with no action are mostly wrong anyway. For example, `\[0-9]+` matches the literal string `[0-9` followed by one or more `]`, because the `\\` escape causes the open bracket to be interpreted as a literal character rather than the start of a character class.